# notepad++ complicated regular expression

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I have a huge HTML file and I'd like to delete all the parts starting with `[sound:` and ending with `<div style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px;'></div>`

Here is a sample of my document:

```
<div class=Answer>
        <div style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 50px;'>你好</div>
        <br />nĭ hăo<br />[sound:pronunciation_zh_你好.mp3]
        <a href='javascript:py.link("ankiplaypronunciation_zh_你好.mp3");' title="pronunciation_zh_你好.mp3" class="replaybutton browserhide">
           <span>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                 <polygon points="11,25 25,16 11,7"/>
                 Replay
              </svg>
           </span>
        </a>
        <span style="display: none;">&#91;sound:pronunciation_zh_你好.mp3&#93;</span><br />
        <div style='color: DarkSlateGray; font-size: 25px;' ></div>
        <br />
        <div style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px;'></div>
     </div>
```

Expected result:

```
<div class=Answer>
        <div style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 50px;'>你好</div>
        <br />nĭ hăo<br />
     </div>
```

I tried using regular expressions in Notepad++ but I can't figure out this one, especially because I always get "invalid expression" probably due to the `<`, `/`, `>` caracters.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: show your regexes.

Comment: I tried this: [sound:*<div style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px;'></div>

Comment: Is there any possibilities for your html files to be minified?

Comment: yes, I can copy/paste it in a minifier. How would this help?

Comment: Try `\[sound:.*((?!^\s*<div style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px;'></div>).*\R*)*.*` (no minification needed)

Comment: Thanks for you help @revo, but it selects all the text starting with [sound:

Comment: and you should replace it with nothing after selection. [Check it here.](https://regex101.com/r/xh7u4m/1)

Comment: Actually, this is a job for an HTML parser if you do this on a large scale.

Comment: It's not a language it's an editor. @wp78de

Comment: I know what Notepad++ is, but still.

Comment: ... but still there is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for this expression and replace it with nothing:

```
\[sound:.*?<div\s+style='font-family:\s+Arial;\s+font-size:\s+15px;'></div>
```